# Matlab - Convert column double to char

Tags: matlab

I need to display in excel a matrix, but my last column display special caracteres in excel.
I want to convert this last column in number or String, to be display correctly.

My matrix

```
data 
   = 'A1' [48]
     'A2' [44]
     'A3' [45]
     'A4' [46]
```

This last column (with brackets) seems to be double.

I want something as this :

```
data 
   = 'A1' 48
     'A2' 44
     'A3' 45
     'A4' 46
```

Comment: How is excel involved ?

Comment: I don't get it. The last column of the input already contains numbers. How does the desired output shown differ from the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is of type cell. If you use

```
data(:,2)=cellfun(@num2str,data(:,2),'UniformOutput',false)
```

then all numbers will show up as strings in the output you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about applying `num2str` to the entire array of numbers, and then converting the output strings back to cells:

```
data(:, 2) = cellstr(num2str(vertcat(data{:, 2})));
```